# trying to do a small login program to import into my main program in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

Good day. Trying to use a CSV file to store usernames and passwords. here is my work:

```
require 'csv'
datab_file = "data.csv"

puts "Enter username"
usrn = gets.chomp

puts "Enter password"
pas = gets.chomp

CSV.open(datab_file, 'a+') {|file|
  final_name = usrn, pas.gsub(',','').split(/\s+/).join(',')
  file.puts final_name
}


puts "Enter username"
username = gets.chomp

puts "Enter password"
password = gets.chomp

people = CSV.read(datab_file)

person = people.find_all do |p|
  p[1] =~ /password/
  puts "member"#person.inspect
end
```

don't why it is not finding the password. Any idea on how to search if the password entered is in the CSV file?

Comment: How does our csv file look like after add some users? Does it look like valid CSV?

Comment: yes it does. e.g: sam,zero @spickermann